# onload not firing and image failing to be drawn

Tags: javascript, onload, drawimage

onload isn't firing in the 'draw()' method, and my image is not getting drawn on the canvas. I have confirmed that the path is correct and the image is there.

I can't find where the problem is. Thank you in advance for advice.

```js
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.gameWidth = 600;
        this.gameHeight = 300;
        this.gravity = 0.7;
        this.canvasName = "gameBox";
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasName)
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    draw(image) {
        let img = document.createElement('IMG');

        this.ctx.fillStyle ='#F00';
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);

        img.onload = function() {
            this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, image.xPos, image.yPos, image.width, image.height);
        }.call(this);

        img.src = image.imageFile;
    }
}
class Sprite {
    constructor(width, height, imageFile, xPos, yPos) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.xVel = 0;
        this.yVel = 0;
    }
}

let game = new Game()
let elephant = new Sprite(21, 13, "./images/elephant.png", game.gameWidth / 2, game.gameHeight - 13);

game.draw(elephant);
```

CORRECT VERSION:
I've rewritten it taking in advice from guest271314, thank you! Still seems overly complex for my liking, but it works.

```js
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.gameWidth = 600;
        this.gameHeight = 300;
        this.gravity = 0.7;
        this.canvasName = "gameBox";
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasName)
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    drawSprite(image, img) {
          this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, image.xPos, image.yPos, image.width, image.height);
    }
    draw(image) {
 let img = document.createElement('IMG');

        this.ctx.fillStyle ='#F00';
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);

        img.onload = this.drawSprite.bind(this, image, img);

        img.src = image.imageFile;
    }
}
class Sprite {
    constructor(width, height, imageFile, xPos, yPos) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.xVel = 0;
        this.yVel = 0;
    }
}

let game = new Game()
let elephant = new Sprite(21, 13, "./images/elephant.png", game.gameWidth / 2, game.gameHeight - 13);

game.draw(elephant);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.call()` chained to the function is a syntax error without parenthesis wrapping the function. `load` callback should not be called until the `load` handler dispatches. You can define the function with a name and use `.bind()`

```
function handleImgLoad() {
  // do stuff
}

img.onload = handleImgLoad.bind(this);
```

Comment: I see, that does make sense. I've added an updated version to my original post, taking in your advice. But I still must be doing something wrong as it's still not drawing.

Comment: Where are `img`, `image.width`, `image.height` defined? `let img = document.createElement('IMG')` is only defined within `draw()`

Comment: @Cuckoo You can define `drawSprite()` to expect `img` and `image` as parameters `drawSprite(img, image) {}` then pass parameters to `.bind()`  `img.onload = this.drawSprite.bind(this, img, image)`. Where is `game.draw()` called in the code at the question?